# Detecting current page when on root page ASP.NET with VB

Tags: asp.net, css

my current code is below. If you visit the root of my webpage http://evanparsons.net/ you will notice that the current page is not highlighted, however when you visit a page, it works. For testing purposes, I had it return the "myPage" value to see why it isn't working... it still returns index.aspx.

```
            Dim pageName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
            While DBReader.Read()

            _link = _link + "<li><a href='" + (DBReader("source")) + "'"
            If ((pageName) = (DBReader("source"))) Then

                _link = _link + "class='current' "

            End If

            _link = _link + pageName

            _link = _link + ">-" + (DBReader("name")) + "-  </a></li>"

            End While
```

Basically, my navigation comes from a master page that scans my database, and as it cycles through it, I want to add a css class called current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried converting them into lower case?

```
If (pageName.ToLower() = (DBReader("source")).ToLower()) Then
```

Comment: thank you sir! Something so simple, I can't believe I overlooked that!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. ;-)